# Getting undefined property error when trying to list entries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to list some entry titles, but getting this Undefined property error. I'm using Laravel 7.

This is my model:

```
class DocumentationItem extends Model
{

    public function docs()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Documentation::class, 'doc_id');
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
$documentation = DB::table('documentations')->where('slug', $docSlug)->first();

$entries = DB::table('documentation_items')->where('doc_id', $documentation->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

return view('frontend.docs.documentation', compact('documentation', 'entries'));
```

And this is the code I'm trying to use in my blade file:

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)
    <li>
       <a href="#">{{ $entry->entry_title }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

The full error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$entry_title
> (View:
> F:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\frontend\docs\partials\doc-sidebar.blade.php)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: post the full error

Comment: edited the post with the error

Comment: You are missing to excecute the query. Add a `->get()` after `$entries = DB::table('documentation_items')->where('doc_id', $documentation->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();`

Comment: Try thi `$entries = DB::table('documentation_items')->where('doc_id', $documentation->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();`

Comment: Ahh.... thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving All Rows From A Table using the table method provided by the DB facade to begin a query. The table method returns a fluent query builder instance for the given table, allowing you to chain more constraints onto the query and then finally retrieve the results of the query using the `get` method:

Try this

```
$entries = DB::table('documentation_items')->where('doc_id', $documentation->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```